# TFS configure variables on Release definition instantiation

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I have a release definition setup with several tasks. When a developer wants to create a release from this definition, i'd like to give them the option of selecting which features they'd like to release (turn on/off tasks). Ideally this would be via the Create Release dialog using a variable or similar.

Can this be done? Or is the only way to achieve this to create a draft release and enable/disable the tasks on each environment? Believe this is prone to error (toggle task on one environment but forget to on another) and this is not an option as administrator has locked editing of definitions (prevent incorrect setup of production releases).

Understand I can create separate release definitions to cover the options but it seems like a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported in TFS currently. The workarounds are just like you mentioned above, to disable and enable those steps or use draft release.

This is a user voice about your request you could vote:
 https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19165690-select-steps-when-create-release